# windows miniredir always tries SMB first when accessing a webdav server. extremely slow

Tags: windows, webdav, smb

I am writing a webdav server for embedded system. Everything goes normal until I tested it with windows client, the miniredir.

It became extremely slow when accessing the data with miniredir. I captured the network traffic and found that everytime I made a move, the miniredir tried to connect to the server via SMB first. (SYN package sent to 137,138,139,445) and the expolrer view would not show until the SMB request failed a few times, which takes more than 20s.

I also tried miniredir with Apache+mod_dav, same delay was observed (make sure the server machine disabled SMB service).

Is there anyone solved this problem? or if there's any work around solution for XP?

BTW: After a few days' debugging, now I believe MS Miniredir is not a qualified WebDAV client. A lot of bugs and shorting comings were reported, but MS didn't do much improvement. http://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/webdav-redirector-list.html

Answer (score 1):

Significant delays can be encountered when accessing WebDAV resources if Internet Explorer is configured to auto-detect proxy servers.  Try following these [instructions for disabling proxy auto-detection](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2445570) and see if that helps.

> After a few days' debugging, now I believe MS Miniredir is not a qualified WebDAV client.

I think this is an overstatement. The only documented issue in XP/SP3 is a by-default lack of support for basic auth, and there is a workaround for this. "When you hear hoofbeats, look for horses, not zebras."

Comment: I have disabled the proxy detection as the doc said, but it didn't help. I found a MS white paper which said a lot about this issue: [link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C523AC7A-5724-48BE-B973-641E805588F4&displaylang=en) . it said that miniredir was designed to try SMB first, to workaround, the server should disable the ping echo in addition to resetting the TCP connection for SMB. It seems sensible , but I tried it out with no luck. And, the server was designed to be a net gateway, there's quite a few applications use ping request for trouble shooting. Painful.

Comment: Yikes, what a pain.  Sorry. :/